# Inject object created in code-behind to ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, bing-maps

Im creating an app using Bing Map and I create an Instance of the map in my XAML-file like this:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="MyMap"/>
```

I need to pass this instance of the Map to my viewModel, which is in another project(PCL), in order to "use" it. I have

I assume that the Map gets created in `this.InitializeComponent()` in the codebehind.

```
public MainPage()
{            
    this.InitializeComponent();                     
}
```

This is also where my DI gets triggered:

```
 public ViewModelLocator()
        {            
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();            
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMap, MyBingMap>();                    
        }
```

`MyBingMap` is the implementation of IMAP that I wish to pass to the VM. But before I do that I need it to have  the instance of the Map that gets created in the code-behind.

I hope my questions is clear enough for someone. 
Im open to all suggestions that can pass `myMap` to the VM.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map itself has a Loaded event which you can use to get the map after it has been loaded.

Comment: This sounds interesting. Would you mind describing a little bit closer how to  use the maps Loaded event in a situation like this? Does it mean that i should not use DI?  

When you say that i can "get the map", does this mean that i can get it from my class that implements IMap? That would be great.

Comment: If you want to create a class that inherits from IMap, you could create a wrapper class for the map since it is a sealed class. Take a look at the approach I used in the linked blog to handle maps in universal apps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbrundritt/archive/2014/06/24/how-to-make-use-of-maps-in-universal-apps.aspx

Comment: I still have some problems getting this to work. You mentioned the maps Loaded event. Is it possible for me to use this as a way to always get the same instance of the map? I tried using the example from you universal blog-post. However, in my case, using DI, my equivalent of your MapView(the class that creates the map) gets called two times and thus creates a second instance of the map.

Comment: The Loaded event will only fire when the map is initially loaded the first time. If you find this fires a second time then you must be reloading a view that has the map (i.e. leave a page and go back to it). If you leave a page and go back to it the page is recreated.